# How can my controller action wait and respond the result of my message driven workflow?

Tags: .net, masstransit, event-bus

I have a legacy client and a WebApi with the controller action `ArticleController.AddArticle()`. The action `ArticleController.AddArticle()` receives a request and returns a response. In between there is a message driven workflow. At the end of the workflow there is a result message. The action `ArticleController.AddArticle()` should return the result message.

The workflow looks sth. like this:

- Client sends HTTP Request to ArticleController.AddArticle()
- ArticleController.AddArticle() sends message to CalcA
- CalcA sends message to CalcB
- CalcB sends message to ArticleController.AddArticle()
- ArticleController.AddArticle() sends HTTP Response to client

```cs
// Pseude code
[HttpPost()]
public async Task<ResultMessage> PostAsync()
{
    await _bus.Publish(/*...*/);
    // Message driven workflow
    var resultMessage = await _bus.SubscribeAndWaitOn<ResultMessage>(/*...*/);
    return resultMessage;
}
```

How can I let the action wait for the result message?

I am using .NET with MassTransit and RabbitMQ. I have found the request/response pattern (https://masstransit.io/documentation/concepts/requests) and it works for a simple message. But is this the right way for large workflows?

Comment: Use the request client, which is documented on that page.

Comment: wouldn't be better to model this process and return the process Id or workflow id to the client. so that the client can then poll to check the status and eventually download the result. Of course you would need a storage to persist this data

Comment: @ChrisPatterson I can use RequestClient to send a message consume the message and respond the result of the consumer. What I want to have is to respond the result at the end of a "workflow" (send A, consume A, send B, consume B, send C, consume C, respond D). Is that possible?

Comment: @MarcoMerola Unfortunately we don't want to change the old client and the old client needs a response that it expects. So we need a wait mechanism on our server.